# Pythonic way to maintain variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a small file utility earlier, and ran into an issue with passing by reference. After reading [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), I set the variable I wanted to pass through as an argument and also as the return value. Within the code below, it is the line:

```
diff = compareDir(path0, path0List, path1, path1List, diff)
```

where diff is the variable I wished to pass by reference.

While this works, it feels rather awkward. I think there must be a better way. In many other languages, I could just set `compareLists()` to have no return value, and use the side-effect of modifying the pass-by-reference argument. Python's pass-by-assignment seems to disallow this.

I am relatively new to python, and would like to know if there is a more pythonic way to resolve my issue. Would it require rethinking the functions entirely? Or is there a nice statement I am unaware of? I'd like to stay away from global variables.

I welcome any and all constructive criticisms and comments. Thanks!

Relevant Code:

```
def comparePaths(path0, path1):
    path0List = os.listdir(path0)
    path1List = os.listdir(path1)

    diff = False
    diff = compareDir(path0, path0List, path1, path1List, diff)
    print()
    diff = compareDir(path1, path1List, path0, path0List, diff)
    return diff

def compareDir(basePath, baseList, comparePath, compareDir, diffVar):
    for entry in baseList:
        #compare to the other folder
        if (not (entry in compareDir)):
            if (not (diffVar)):
                diffVar = True
                print ("Discreptancies found. The following files are different:")
                print (str(entry) + " doesn\'t exist in " + str(comparePath))
            else:
                print (str(entry) + " doesn\'t exist in " + str(comparePath))
    return diffVar
```

Comment: If you want to cut down the parameters to something where you just call `compareLists()`, I think you may need to reconsider your approach. Perhaps by storing your values in a dictionary because that way you can modify the key/value pairs anywhere in the namespace.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that is an excellent suggestion. I may do just that.

Comment: The linked answer does a perfectly good job of explaining the distinction between mutable and immutable objects.  `diff=False` is immutable.  `diff=[False]` is mutable.

Comment: Just to be clear @hpaulj diff=[False] is using a class wrapper per the accepted answer's last suggestion in the linked question, correct? Or am I missing something in your notation there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in Python, the bool type is by definition immutable, the only way to modify a bool variable inside a function without reassigning it (and without defining it as a global variable) is to store it in a mutable type instance. ie:

- Storing it in a mutable data structure (list, dict, ...) and pass this data structure to the function.
- Having it as an attribute of a mutable object, and pass this object to the function.

Comment: Thanks Dim. You wouldn't happen to have a pydocs reference to mutable vs immutable types? I found [this reference on mutable vs. immutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) but could use more info.

Comment: No, but I think everything is there:

- numeric types (int, float, complex) are immutables.
- str, bytes and tuple are immutable sequences.
- list and bytearray are mutables.
- set is mutable, frozenset is immutable.
- dict is mutable.

Comment: Thanks @Dim I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has multiple possible solutions.

You can add `nonlocal` modifier (`global` prior to python3) for your diff variable to modify from inside function and have changes visible from outside.

```
    diff = False

    def compareDir(basePath, baseList, comparePath, compareDir):
        nonlocal diff
        for entry in baseList:
                    ...
                    diff = True

    compareDir(path0, path0List, path1, path1List)
    print()
    compareDir(path1, path1List, path0, path0List)
    return diff
```

Or you can have OOP solution with `differ` object and self.diff as explicit state of that object.

```
class differ(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.diff = False
    def compareDir(self, basePath, baseList, comparePath, compareDir):
        ...
              self.diff = True
        ...

    def comparePaths(self, path0, path1):
```

Latter solution is super helpful if you need to do a lot of work in some 'context' and frequently need to change shared state.